# Object DBNull Error

Tags: asp.net, dbnull

I tried to follow some examples on the internet without success

I'm trying the following in a  **GridView1_RowDataBound methode**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(drv["Created_Date"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") == "01-01-1900" || (drv["Created_Date"].ToString().Equals(DBNull.Value))) //Check for this date
        {
            e.Row.Cells[11].Text = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still receiving a **Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(drv["Created_Date"].ToString())
```

However you should switch the first and second values in the if-statement. You are checking if the `Created_Date` is `null` AFTER you cast it. So if it is `null`, your code will still throw an error. So it is better to do something like this

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(drv["Created_Date"].ToString()) || Convert.ToDateTime(drv["Created_Date"]) == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
```